docusaurus with @sillsdev/docu-notion
I working docusaurus with @sillsdev/docu-notion for pull data from notion. It working fine with locally. but in site production alert error when click any page in sitebar
ERROR
Maximum call stack size exceeded
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at t. [as capture] (eval at  (https://help.krubkrong.com/cdn-cgi/zaraz/s.js?z=JTdCJTIyZXhlY3V0ZWQlMjIlM0ElNUIlNUQlMkMlMjJ0JTIyJTNBJTIyS3J1Ymtyb25nJTIwRG9jdW1lbnRhdGlvbiUyMiUyQyUyMnglMjIlM0EwLjUyMzIzNzUxOTM2NDg2MjIlMkMlMjJ3JTIyJTNBMTkyMCUyQyUyMmglMjIlM0ExMDgwJTJDJTIyaiUyMiUzQTk5MyUyQyUyMmUlMjIlM0ExOTIwJTJDJTIybCUyMiUzQSUyMmh0dHBzJTNBJTJGJTJGaGVscC5rcnVia3JvbmcuY29tJTJGZG9jcyUyRnVzZXIlMjIlMkMlMjJyJTIyJTNBJTIyJTIyJTJDJTIyayUyMiUzQTI0JTJDJTIybiUyMiUzQSUyMlVURi04JTIyJTJDJTIybyUyMiUzQS00MjAlMkMlMjJxJTIyJTNBJTVCJTVEJTdE:1:994), :4:174)
at e. (https://us-assets.i.posthog.com/static/array.js:1:115107)
at Array.forEach ()
at z (https://us-assets.i.posthog.com/static/array.js:1:5725)
at o (https://us-assets.i.posthog.com/static/array.js:1:115004)
at e.value (https://us-assets.i.posthog.com/static/array.js:1:115156)
at e.value (https://us-assets.i.posthog.com/static/array.js:1:115435)
